# How to validate open source R packages; i.e, eliminate malicious packages

Tags: r

Open source R packages are available at sites such as https://cran.r-project.org. Anyone can develop any package that might be useful to use.

I am exploring to find out if there is any way to validate if a package is safe to use or can be considered malicious or questionable.

I am new to R programming. However, R has been available for a while now and I am curious to know how other programmers and companies have solved this question.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about R packages on CRAN, or about *any* R package available *anywhere*?

Comment: You may want to check out [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/are-R-packages-safe-td4727189.html) on whether and the extent to which R packages on CRAN should be considered "safe", as well as [this R package](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/rpwnd) giving "examples of all the ways you can get 'pwnd' by R packages."